# How to solve $(a^2-x^2) y''- 2 x y'+12 y=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(a^2-x^2) y''-2xy'-12y=0$

> The general form may be written in
>   $(a^2-x^2)\bigg(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\bigg)-2x\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)+n(n+1)y=0$

This question was asked in my exam and I proceeded in the standard series method taking $x=0$ as a ordinary point, but is it the right way ? Does this equation have something to do with Legendre's differential equation?

In case of duplicate,I am extremely sorry ! ( I am unable to find any if such )

Comment: Do you know Legendre polynomials ? Otherwise, $y=0$ is a good candidate.

Comment: Yes just basic as rodrigure formula, go on !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Comment: Can u share some steps ,how to solve this differential equation ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: $y=0$, and multiples. ;-)

Comment: Please write the equation as $(a^2-x^2) y''-2xy'+12y=0$ in your question.

Answer (score 0):

$(a^2-x^2) y''-2xy'+12y=0 \implies (a^2-x^2) y''-2xy'+3 (3+1)y=0$

This is a Legendre's differential equation for $n = 3$.

For solution of this differential equation you can follow this pdf http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode13.pdf

or you can follow this book as a reference "Special Functions & Their Applications" by N. N. Lebedev (Dover Publications Inc. Chapter $7$)

Comment: Legendre's eqn  is for $a=1$ how to solve this for any $a$ ?

Comment: "Special Functions & Their Applications" by N. N. Lebedev (Dover Publications Inc. Chapter 7)

Comment: Look the procedure is same but you can't get the exact. Try yourself, and tell use where you stuck.

Comment: Bhai me class 10 me hoon , aur merko basic d.e  to solve karna aata he,lekin ye sab nahin aata mene legendre eqn padh rakha he aur mere hisaab se $a=0$ pe isko $x=0$ pe power series nahin expand kar sakte.

Comment: Aap konse class me ho ?